Why does flow separation cause an increase in pressure drag?
Why does flow separation cause an increase in pressure drag?
In this question, I am relying on this answer for some information, so it might be essential to read that answer to understand what I am talking about, but I will give a quick rundown.
In that answer, it says that when flow separates the pressure of the separated area is actually higher than if it was attached. If you apply this to a wing, the separated flow area will have a higher pressure, therefore not creating as much lift (assuming the higher pressure separated flow was on top of the wing like in a normal stall).

However, lift is directly linked to drag. So if you don't make as much lift, you don't make as much drag.
So when flow separates, it causes a loss of lift. Wouldn't this also cause a 'loss' of drag?

Let's use a cylinder as an example:

Imagine in this picture the flow was attached. According to the answer I linked, the pressure behind the object will be lower when the flow is attached. The linked answer also mentions the inverse is true, so the pressure in separated flow would be higher (although still low pressure).
If that is the case, why would flow separation cause an increase in pressure drag? If the pressure is actually higher behind an object in separated flow, why wouldn't the drag actually decrease?

We can have a look at the pressure distribution of the airfoil in attached and separated flow conditions.
This is shown in this image from Fundamentals of Aerodynamics, by John D. Anderson, 6th edition, p.391

The image shows suction downwards. In the previous question, we talked about the point of separation (i.e. the front of the airfoil). Here we see that the earlier statements were confirmed, and the pressure for the attached flow case is much lower (thus more lift) than for the separated case.
Looking at the rear of the airfoil, we see that the opposite is true and that the separated case has more suction than the separated case.
So it's not categorically true that the pressure is higher/lower for separated flow compared to attached flow, it depends on the region.

In the front: less suction for separated flow
In the rear: more suction for separated flow

This gets compounded by the direction of the local flow, see this image below, from the same source:

Here we see something interesting, the arrows are pointed more vertically in the front region, and more horizontally in the rear region.
This is due to local curvature of the airfoil:

In the front: vertically oriented arrows
In the rear: horizontally oriented arrows

We can now combine both findings:

In the front: less suction for separated flow, vertically oriented arrows -> less vertical force for the separated flow: less lift
In the rear: more suction for separated flow, horizontally oriented arrows -> more horizontal force for the separated flow: more drag


Thanks for your answer. So using this same logic, why would separation on a cylinder increase the drag? The curvature over a cylinder is constant, so the rear half wouldn’t become lower pressure once flow separates like it does with an airfoil. Basically, with a cylinder the pressure would be lower on the rear side compared to separated flow, so wouldn’t drag decrease when flow separates over a cylinder?

(Essentially all separated flow on a cylinder would be the same pressure (mostly) because the cylinder is symmetrical, unlike an airfoil)

There is one theory I have: Like how the back of an airfoil turns low pressure when it stalls instead of becoming more high pressure (like the other parts of the wing), the back of a cylinder does the same thing in a flow-separated-condition. Is this correct? ("The same thing" meaning the stalled area of a cylinder is low pressure when it stalls)

(If that doesn’t make sense I can try to explain it better)


However, lift is directly linked to drag. So when flow separates, it causes a loss of lift. Wouldn't this also cause a 'loss' of drag?

Lift is not directly related to drag: it is related to induced drag. So yes, when the wing stalls, lift reduces and consequently induced drag reduces as well (at least if stall is "uniform" along the wing and therefore the spanwise lift distribution remains more or less the same - for example it remains elliptic before and after the stall).
Anyway you're forgetting the viscous drag. When the wing stalls, the boundary layer drastically grows making the viscous drag grow as well.
Normally in aviation this second effect (the increase in viscous drag) is bigger than the first one (the reduction - if any - in induced drag) and therefore stall  produces a net increase of drag. There are anyway cases where the opposite is true and a stalled wing actually generates a lower total drag.

@RobertDiGiovanni: just corrected, thanks for the comment

Thanks for the answer. I did read the link, but I having a bit of trouble understanding why in some cases flow separation will reduce drag. Could you generally explain why in some cases drag will reduce with flow separation?

@RobertDiGiovanni As said in Sophit’s answer, in some cases flow separation will reduce drag (which you suggested they add to the answer). Is there any good explanation for why in some cases it will reduce drag? Essentially I am asking you the same thing as my other comment on this answer.

@RobertDiGiovanni I think I understand that part fairly well. The part that is confusing is why in some cases induced drag will be increased instead of decreased. My main question is what differs between the case where separation increases induced drag  and when it decreases induced drag. (I do think I didn’t explain this very well in my last comment)

@Wyatt: how total drag reduces in case of a stalled F1 spoiler is nicely described at the beginning of the paper I linked: "in the case of the finite wing with low aspect ratio, the induced drag is dominant and is proportional to the downforce. Therefore, flow separation on the wing increases the profile drag while simultaneously reducing the induced drag, resulting in a decrease in the total aerodynamic drag."

@sophit I see, thanks for pointing that out. Just to clarify, wouldn’t this make it depend on aspect ratio to determine if induced drag would increase or decrease in a stall?

(I can explain what made me think this if that helps)


Why does flow separation cause an increase in pressure drag?

The pressure drag you're talking about is only a portion of the total drag, which originates from the turbulent section of the boundary layer (TBL).

Source: Nasa.
When the angle of attack increases, the transition occurs closer to the stagnation point at the leading edge, the laminar section of the boundary layer (LBL) is reduced. After the transition the boundary layer becomes turbulent. The wide wake following the airfoil greatly changes the pressure field at the rear of the airfoil and behind it. Comparing a laminar pressure field (plain curve) and a boundary layer with a turbulent portion (dotted):

Source: ibid.
This the TBL and the induced wake which increase the pressure drag. You can see the lower pressure at the trailing stagnation point (which is no more a stagnation point with a TBL).

Source: ibid.
The pressure drag is different from the friction drag present both in the LBL and the TBL.

The friction drag is due to air viscosity: Air adheres to the airfoil, the airfoil is slowed down due to the tendency of air streamlines at different velocities to shear.

The pressure drag is not this shear effect, it results from a difference of static pressure applied to the front (stagnation pressure) of the airfoil and to the rear of the airfoil. With a boundary layer entirely laminar (e.g. at 0-lift angle) these two pressures are equal and there is no net pressure drag.
But if there is a TBL portion, then the wake creates a wide volume of low pressure at the rear of the airfoil. There is now a difference between front and rear pressures resulting in a net pressure drag which slows the airfoil.


Pressure drag is due to turbulence of different sorts

In the wake of the TBL,

for a 3D wing in the tip vortices.



So when flow separates, it causes a loss of lift. Wouldn't this also cause a 'loss' of drag?

Turbulence creates a pressure drag which doesn't exist when the BL is entirely laminar. Friction drag and pressure drag sum up. Comparing an ideal flow (all laminar) with a boundary layer where the TBL exists:

Source: ibid.
While TBL decreases the amount of lift, it increases the amount of total drag (due to the additional pressure drag). The larger the angle of attack, the longer the TBL, the larger the additional pressure drag.

Here is how I have visualized this process in the past but now I am not sure it is correct, and would appreciate comments/corrections.
Using the example above of a cylindrical object with a wake of separated flow, we can imagine replacing the wake with a protrusion of solid material affixed to the downstream side of the cylinder, producing a "teardrop" cross-section instead of a circular one. The teardrop occupies the full volume of the separated region which means the flow immediately adjacent to the wall of the teardrop shape is not separated but instead follows the contour of the teardrop. Any drag effects caused by the separation dynamics are then absent because we have streamlined the shape of the body over which the flow is happening.
Now you can also see that as the flow striking the upstream side of the object splits at the stagnation point and begins moving sideways, it ballistically overshoots the actual contour of the body and fails to follow that contour- tracing out a profile that is larger in cross-section than the body itself. Inside that profile, the flow is also separated- it is as if the object presents a larger profile than its actual dimensions, and therefore more drag.
Putting a slightly sharper shape on the upstream side of the object parts the flow more gradually and yields an effective wake cross-section smaller than the case where the flow was separated.
Continuing this process of reshaping the object to eliminate flow separation all around the surface of the object finally yields an elongated object much larger in volume than the original round cross-section yet with the same or less total drag as the round cross-section.
Does this way of looking at things have any merit? Please advise.

This is a good way to interpret what happens. Proof: Take the famous golfball with and without dimples. The smooth golfball has early, laminar separation and a huge wake, the dimpled golfball a later, turbulent separation and a much smaller wake.

Appreciate the upvotes but this question deserves a better answer.
The cylinder picture in the question really tells all.

where is the center of low pressure when flow separates?

Not only how low the pressure is compared with attached flow but in what direction?
It seems clear that when flow separates the suction (center of low pressure) moves further behind the object.  In the case of the cylinder, directly behind it.
So, one can see the resultant drag vector depends not only on low pressure, but also on the direction of the pressure vector relative to the flight path of the object.
As Peter K pointed out, at a high enough Reynolds number, with flow behaving more in a invicid manner, flow will remain attached over a larger area.
Note that increase in pressure is linear, but shrinkage of the low pressure area behind the object is a square function (area) when flow remains more fully attached.

@Wyatt finding the formula for induced drag here we see L$^2$ in the numerator.  So, technically, induced drag decreases as lift decreases.

The flow past a cylinder is a good way to explain what happens with airfoils, too. So let's look what NASA has to show for different levels of viscosity:

Of particular interest is the theoretical case of frictionless flow on the upper left (case 1): The streamlines look symmetrical, and so does its pressure distribution (the dot-dashed line in the plot below, source).

This means without friction the air pressure does as much pushing from the rear as from the front. The suction around the middle is also equal, and all pressures combine to zero resulting force: Dragless flow! The same happens with airfoils in the theoretical case of inviscid flow, even as lift is produced. This is known as d'Alembert's paradox.
With a high enough Reynolds number (think millions), friction becomes less dominant and the flow becomes more similar to the inviscid case as Re increases. Typical airplane Reynolds numbers are in that region, so with attached flow there is indeed some pushing done on the rear part of the airfoil by the recompressed and still attached flow.
Flow separation, however, occurs when that recompression cannot be completed because the speed in the lower part of the boundary layer drops below zero. With incomplete pressure recovery, the rear part of the wing still experiences mild suction (the typical pressure coefficient in separated flow is -0.2) and instead of being pushed, the wing is sucked backwards a bit. This will show up as increased drag, caused by separation.
At the same time, the airfoil-boundary layer-combination will look like a wing with less angle of attack, so the suction peak at the forward upper section of the airfoil will shrink and less leading edge thrust will pull the airfoil forward. This also contributes to the drag increase with separated flow.

Thanks for your answer. So to explain this I'm going to use the case one picture. When the flow goes over the back half of the cylinder, it turns towards the centerline. When this turning is being done, low pressure is created. This low pressure is actually lower than that of separated flow, so wouldn't drag actually decrease when flow separates on a cylinder? I'm going off of this answer when writing this.

@Wyatt Pressure is proportional to the distance between streamlines. If the streamline pattern is identical, so is the pressure. And around the two stagnation points (1 forward, 1 backward), the distance is largest, and so is pressure. None of the pictures in the other answer show inviscid flow, and low speed, fully laminar flow is very different from inviscid flow.

I think my confusion is because I'm not thinking of inviscid flow. I'm thinking of a flow that (theoretically) stays attached but that isn't inviscid. If you look at the first picture in @ROIMaison's answer to this question, it shows a graph illustrating what I'm attempting to explain. The pressure with attached flow is lower, which would mean attached flow behind a cylinder (in non-inviscid flow) would have a lower pressure than separated, causing more drag to be made in non separated flow.

(if that doesn't make sense I can attempt to explain it better)

@Wyatt The lines in ROIMason's pictures are not streamlines but isobars. BIG difference! Also, the first picture shows low Reynolds number flow, like dropping a marble in honey. This is very different from what hapens in air.
